# Any way to process payments for 3rd parties without using Adaptive Payments?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Our software collects payments on behalf of 3rd parties using Adaptive Payments (redirect as well as embedded options). We don't split/chain the payments in any way... just act as middle man shuttling the full payment from payer to primary receiver.

Unfortunately, Adaptive Payments is ancient technology and the guest checkout option is a TERRIBLE user experience. We'd like to be able to create our own custom guest (credit card) checkout process and not have to rely on the Paypal redirect page OR the lightbox (embedded) option. Ideally, it would be great to use Direct Payment API however, from what I understand, this would require all our customers to have Paypal Payments Pro account ($35 per month) which would be a huge roadblock to adoption for us.

Is there any way for us to collect payments on behalf of 3rd parties using our own custom guest checkout but WITHOUT requiring our customers to upgrade to Paypal Pro account?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Express Checkout with Parallel Payments ;

Express Checkout with Parallel : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-parallelPayments/

Or you can use MassPay. It depends on your need.

MassPay : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/mass-pay/

Comment: Thanks but I believe Express Checkout is done via lightbox which is too old school (also the Paypal guest checkout is terrible UX... requires WAY too much information). We want our own custom checkout experience. thx